# Why $\nabla \times (\nabla \times a) = -(\nabla \cdot \nabla)a + \nabla(\nabla \cdot a)$?

Tags: vector-analysis

Why $\nabla \times (\nabla \times a) = - (\nabla \cdot \nabla)a + \nabla(\nabla \cdot a)$ ?
I can derive this equation with the identity $\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{jkl}=-\delta_{jl}\delta_{im} + \delta_{jm}\delta_{li}$.
But it's not obvious compare to the identities like $\nabla \cdot \nabla \cdot (\nabla a)=0$.
Thinking scalar vectors $a,b, b\times (b\times a)$ is parallel to a,but when b is replaced by $\nabla, \nabla(\nabla \cdot a)$　appear which is not parallel to a. What does $\nabla(\nabla \cdot a)$ represents for ?
Is there any intuitive or easy way to derive the equation above ?

Comment: $\nabla(\nabla \cdot \mathbf a) = \left(\dfrac {\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac {\partial\mathbf a}{\partial x}+\frac {\partial\mathbf a}{\partial y}+\frac {\partial\mathbf a}{\partial z}\right),\dfrac {\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac {\partial\mathbf a}{\partial x}+\frac {\partial\mathbf a}{\partial y}+\frac {\partial\mathbf a}{\partial z}\right),\dfrac {\partial}{\partial z}\left(\frac {\partial\mathbf a}{\partial x}+\frac {\partial\mathbf a}{\partial y}+\frac {\partial\mathbf a}{\partial z}\right)\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec{\nabla}=\sum \vec{e_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$.

So you are only doing "classical" vector products. If it holds true for any vector $\vec{b}$, there is no reason it should not hold true for $\vec{\nabla}$.
Can you show us what was you issue in detail?

Comment: I'm sorry .I was wrong.

Comment: I want to close this question. I'm very sorry to waste your time .

Comment: By doing classical vector manipulation , I got $b×(b×a) =  -(b・b)a+(a・b)b $ successfully

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\nabla \times (\nabla \times a) =& \nabla \times (\partial_i a_j \varepsilon_{ijk} \bf{e_k} )\\
=& \partial_n \partial_i a_j \varepsilon_{ijk} \varepsilon_{nkp} \bf{e_p}  \\
[\nabla \times (\nabla \times a)]_p=& \partial_n \partial_i a_j \varepsilon_{ijk} \varepsilon_{pnk}\\
=& \partial_n \partial_i a_j(\delta_{ip} \delta_{jn} - \delta_{in} \delta_{jp})\\
=& \partial_j \partial_p a_j - \partial_i \partial_i a_p\\
[(\nabla \cdot \nabla)a]_p = & (\nabla \cdot \nabla) a_p = \partial_i \partial_i a_p\\
[\nabla(\nabla \cdot a)]_p = & \partial_p \partial_j a_j = \partial_j \partial_p a_j \\
\nabla \times (\nabla \times a) =& -(\nabla \cdot \nabla)a + \nabla(\nabla \cdot a)
\end{align}